# Metpy sounding for data just above the surface

Tags: python, metpy

I'm using `Metpy` to create sounding profiles of data I have.

The data itself only goes up to about one kilometer above the surface. Is there a way to visualize this on a sounding using `Metpy`? I'm currently using the `SkewT` function within `Metpy`, but obviously this is more conducive for data that goes well into the upper regions of the troposphere. I've set the y limits so that the data is easier to see since the pressure doesn't vary much with the data, but it's very squished and not really great at visualizing the data. So is there another component of `Metpy` that allows nice, quality sounding profiles to be made for atmospheric data that represents only a small portion of the atmosphere?

Answer (score 0):

Bringing over the answer from [MetPy's discussion board](https://github.com/Unidata/MetPy/discussions/2847):

The challenge here is that skewT gets challenging with changing plot shapes. SkewT in MetPy by default sets a fixed aspect of 80.5 which locks in the ratio of horizontal and vertical plot ranges and keeps things looking "like a skew-T". The knobs you have available:

1. Manually specify your x limits--for the plot above things look better if you do skew.ax.set_xlim(10, 25).
2. By default, MetPy tells Matplotlib to adjust the box to keep right aspect based on the data limits. You could change this with skew.ax.set_adjustable('datalim').
3. Override MetPy's fixed aspect ratio with skew.ax.set_aspect(new_aspect_value)--our default is 80.5. I don't recommend this, though, because it can lead to weird slopes of things on plots, though.